# XCode Swift transpile strings during compliation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am maintaining an app that has an external web service dependency where the suffixes of some strings in models are identical (e.g. `MyField`) but all prefixes are dependent on which service it is. We have multiple schemes that compile multiple versions of these apps, and we include different `Constants.swift` file, so in the code these strings look like `"\(Constants.ServerPrefix)MyField"`.

This `sort of` works but in reality means that the app has to insert those prefixes at runtime, and there are hundreds of thousands of lines of text (think `sql` queries) with these.

I was wondering if there is a way to write a MACRO or something similar so that XCode replaces that `\(Constants.ServerPrefix)` during compilation rather than at runtime?

Also, it would be perfect if that worked with `CodingKeys` enum because right now i can not use runtime constants in my enum string values, so we have to go with a custom `KeyEncodingStrategy`.

Comment: Maybe not Xcode per se, and Swift has no "macros" (there is no precompilation), but I've certainly written ruby scripts that modify the code files at the start of build. I'm pretty sure there are plenty of tools for this sort of thing: just google "code generation" or similar. To that extent it sounds like fairly standard stuff.

Comment: Use Obj-C, it has macros :)